# In Xcode, how can I register a device to test on it, without having a paid Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, apple-developer, apple-id

I am trying to test an app in a real device, using XCode 9.

In Xcode > General > "Automatically manage signing" I get this error: **Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.**

I have tried physically plugging in an iPod, an iPad and an iPhone. They all show up in iTunes, and also in XCode under Windows > "Devices and Simulators", but XCode simply doesn't register anything.

I also tried to go to the website to register the devices manually, but it seems I cannot even access this website without having a paid Apple developer account?

I do NOT have a paid Apple developer account, but I do have the Apple ID. I know that I can test in a real device without an account because in this page https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/ under **Benefits and Resources** the **Sign in with Apple ID** column has **Test on Device** checked.

Please, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 10):

At the top of the Xcode window, from left to right, after the Run and the Stop buttons, there is another button which displays the tooltip "Set the active scheme" when you hover the mouse over it.

This button lets you choose a simulator. But once your device is plugged in it also let you select that device. Once you select your device, the problem disappears.

**Note to those using Xcode to run code developed for Google's Flutter:** You probably must also select `Product` > `Run` in Xcode, before you are able to go the device to trust the certificate, under the device's `General` > `Device Management`.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do when I test on a device is by selecting general device before I archive the build, and then after you follow the prompts after the build, choose install on a device.

If you are really set on just being able to run directly without archiving, make sure that you are signed in with your apple id (the only reason you would need to pay would be if you are submitting to the app store, so you don't have to worry about that) under accounts (XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts), and then replug your device.

And if that doesn't work, try following the instructions on this site: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/ under Registera Single Device.

Comment: Thanks, but those instructions only work if you actually have a developer account, otherwise it simply doesn't let you access the page it refers to in the instructions. However, in the last 5 minutes I seem to have found the solution and will post it here in a moment.

Comment: You can always sign up for a developers account for free using your Apple ID. They don't ask for payment unless you are publishing to the store

Comment: That's good to know. Apple's website seems to imply you must pay to get that account.

Comment: It is a little confusing, but the developer account is free but the program is the paid part. Why they decided to do it that way is a good question

Comment: For future use if you ever decide to make a free dev account, just follow this guide: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-to-create-a-free-apple-developer-account-xcode/